# TypeError: EnumMeta.__call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation, webautomation

I'm looking to setup a webdriver in a script as a headless. I'm able to run it as a non headless way but when i'm creating an instance of the Option() it says me missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

```
chrome_options = Options()
```

Here's a replication of the issue I'm having on the project.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webbrowser import Chrome
from ssl import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


class PythonOrg():

    def Setup(self):
        self.chrome_options = Options()
        self.chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        # self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())) #not a headless
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

    
    def GetLink(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get('https://www.python.org')
        print(driver.title)
        driver.close()


inst = PythonOrg()


inst.Setup()
inst.GetLink()
```

Note: I'm new to Python!

Comment: Could you add the traceback to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You imported a wrong import.
Instead of

```py
from ssl import Options
```

It should be

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

Comment: This works, One more question though as I'm new to python. When I run this script, it gets executed fine but, I see the process is still running. How can I end or exit from that. once the job get done.

Comment: It's not a difficult question, but this is another, new issue. Please accept the given here answer to make indication this question is resolved and then ask a new question for that

Answer (score 0):

for chrome_options add self.

and use from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options not from ssl import Options

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webbrowser import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

class PythonOrg():

    def Setup(self):
        self.chrome_options = Options()
        self.chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        # self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())) #not a headless
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.chrome_options)

    
    def GetLink(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get('https://www.python.org')
        print(driver.title)
        driver.close()


inst = PythonOrg()


inst.Setup()
inst.GetLink()
```

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that I missed it when I copied it over here, That will not solve the issue.

Comment: importing it from Selenium.webdriver.chrome.options does work.